# This program not executing find the faulty code - Duplicate Strings in a linked list

Tags: java

The actual program is removing duplicate strings by first storing the strings in linked list without using Linked list class of Java we should use only methods of String Class.

The program is not executing please help me through get it executed.

The problem is like this :

- Find and remove the duplicate strings in a linked list.
- Store the strings in a linked list and then traverse it to find the duplicates, delete them from the list and do the proper linking of the previous and the next element in the list.

**NOTE:** Don’t use the methods of `LinkedList` class of Java, write your own logic. Although, you can use the methods of the String class.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

// Class name should be "Source",
// otherwise solution won't be accepted
public class Source {
    class Node {
        int data;
        Node next;

        public Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
        }
    }
    public Node head = null;
    public Node tail = null;

    public void addNode(int data) {
        Node newNode = new Node(data);
        if (head == null) {
            head = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        } else {
            tail.next = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }
    }

    public void removeDuplicate() {
        Node current = head, index = null, temp = null;
        if (head == null) {
            return;

        } else {
            while (current != null) {
                temp = current;
                index = current.next;

                while (index != null) {
                    if (current.data == index.data) {
                        temp.next = index.next;
                    } else {
                        temp = index;

                    }
                    index = index.next;
                }
                current = current.next;
            }
        }
    }
    public void display() {
        Node current = head;
        if (head == null) {
            System.out.println("List is empty : ");
            return;
        }
        while (current != null) {
            System.out.println(current.data + " ");
            current = current.next;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Source sList = new Source();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n, m;

    n = in.nextInt();
    m = in.nextInt();
    for (int i = 1; i < m; i++) {
        sList.addNode( in.nextInt());
    }

    sList.display();
    sList.removeDuplicate();
    sList.display();
}
```

Comment: You are using data as int , shouldn't it be string? Also what is the error you are facing . Please specify the error also

Comment: First, can you explain "The program is not executing". Second, `removeDuplicate()` will have an issue if `tail` is removed. Third, in `main` what is `n`? Fourth, in `main` you only loop `m-1` times.

Comment: Thanks Harmandeep I didn't noticed the thing which is very important.

Comment: _The program is not executing please help me through get it executed._ What does that mean, exactly? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
public class Source {

    class Node {
        int data;
        Node next;

        public Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
        }
    }

    public Node head = null;
    public Node tail = null;

    public void addNode(int data) {
        Node newNode = new Node(data);
        if (head == null) {
            head = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        } else {
            tail.next = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }
    }

    public void removeDuplicate() {
        Node current = head, nextNode, temp;
        if (head == null) {
            return;

        } else {
            while (current != null) {
                temp = current;
                nextNode = current.next;

                while (nextNode != null) {
                    if (current.data == nextNode.data) {
                        temp.next = nextNode.next;
                    } else {
                        temp = nextNode;

                    }
                    nextNode = nextNode.next;
                }
                current = current.next;
            }
        }
    }

    public void display() {
        Node current = head;
        if (head == null) {
            System.out.println("List is empty : ");
            return;
        }
        while (current != null) {
            System.out.println(current.data + " ");
            current = current.next;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Source sList = new Source();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int numberOfNodes;

        numberOfNodes = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        for (int i = 1; i < numberOfNodes; i++) {
            sList.addNode(scanner.nextInt());
        }

        sList.display();
        sList.removeDuplicate();
        sList.display();
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

, output

```
5
1 1 3 2 2
1
1
3
2

1
3
2
```

Comment: Super extraordinary

Comment: Can you tell me how to find it out for string

Comment: Just change the data type from `int` to `String`

Comment: And for the comparison, use `if(current.data.equals(nextNode.data))`